# How to stop a while-loop when number has reached 3 decimal points?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am calculating the root of a number and the loop should stop when there are 3 decimal points.

How can I do that?

---

**Edit:**

Code looks like this:

```
public static double hsqrt(double a){
    double val, res = 1;

    do {
        val = res;
        res = 0.5*(val + a/val);
    } while (res - val <= 1E-3);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: What's the algorithm you use?

Comment: Using basic Heron function : Xn+1 = 1/2 * (Xn + a/Xn)

Comment: Hint: "the number of correct digits of the approximation roughly doubles with each iteration" - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method

Comment: "3 deciml points" - Do you mean 3 significant figures?  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

Comment: The simplest way is to calculate the square of your square root approximation in every step and calculate the order of magnitude of its difference from the original number.

Comment: The efficient way would be using the convergence formula given by the Wikipedia page I mentioned above. It looks like you get at least 3 significant digits after 3 iterations.

Comment: Just iterate until the the current value - previous value is less than or equal to .001. You may need to apply `Math.abs()`.

Comment: It only goes one time through the loop